# Cron jobs when running multiple instances on the same DB

Tags: wp-cron, cron

I have a user using my plugin that has multiple AWS instances hosting WP and pointing to the same database. One of the jobs of my plugins is to run a large number of small jobs.

I was thinking of using `wp_schedule_single_event` to schedule the jobs but I'm not sure how that will work with multiple instances. Each job will have unique parameters so there won't be any duplication.

**Question**:
Will each instance try to run the same job or will WordPress be able to resolve this so that each job is only run once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question: Will each instance try to run the same job

Yes! If you have 5 machines running the same site, they'll all try to run the cron job. It'll be inconsistent, but if machine 1 triggers WP Cron and there's an event ready to run, and machine 2 triggers WP Cron, then machine 2 will also see that event if the timing is right and attempt to process it.

> or will WordPress be able to resolve this so that each job is only run once?

Nope, it can't. You can try adding a lock of sorts, but it can't fix the problem, only prevent it in some scenarios

---

What you really need is to disable WP Cron in your config and run it via a system level cron job on a single machine. Or better yet, install a cron service such as cavalcade

Comment: That's what I suspected, thanks for the confirmation!